# Python3 - call method from parent class

Tags: python, inheritance, python-3.x

I need to run `say_hello()` method from `MyException` class. Is it possible?

```
class MyClass:

    def say_hello():
        print('Hello!')

    class MyException(Exception):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            # say_hello()
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    try:
        do_something()
    except Exception:
        raise self.MyException("Something goes wrong, I'll just say hello")
```

Comment: There is no inheritance or parent classes here.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I probably describe problem in wrong way. I need to run `say_hello()` method from `MyException` class. Is it possible?

Comment: Not unless you have an instance of `MyClass`, e.g. __init__ takes a MyClass instance or `say_hello()` is a class method. The formatting you have here makes MyException just a nested class of MyClass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inherit MyClass, which I assume is your intent(???):

```
class MyClass:
    def say_hello(self):
       print('Hello!')

class MyException(MyClass, Exception):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.say_hello()
        super(MyException, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Or you can make it a static method (given `say_hello()` doesn't have a self argument, maybe this is what you meant), but this makes it no better than a function call:

```
class MyClass:
    @staticmethod
    def say_hello():
       print('Hello!')

class MyException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        MyClass.say_hello()
        super(MyException, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Or take instance of MyClass

```
class MyClass:
    def say_hello(self):
       print('Hello!')

class MyException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        instance.say_hello()
        super(MyException, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

exc = MyException(MyClass(), ...)
```

Comment: Thanks! I used the last example.

Answer (score 1):

No. Nested classes are not special in Python, and get no access to the containing class. Because of this, there is rarely a reason to use them.

I suspect you are coming from Java. You don't need `MyClass` at all here; just define both `say_hello` and `MyException` at module level.

Comment: I try build much more bigger library than example in question, but @achampion explain me everything.